# Why doesn't the Objects Linked to Other Objects (OLOO) pattern use Object.create to set key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I came across this pattern in Kyle Simpson's book and which he calls 'OLOO' (see title). Many other sources too accredit him for this pattern, which I find odd because there is nothing novel about it. It goes all the way back to 2008 (page 50 of JavaScript: The Good Parts). Regardless, here is Kyle Simpson's code:

```
var Foo = {
    init: function(who) {
        this.me = who;
    },
    identify: function() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
    }
};

var Bar = Object.create( Foo );

Bar.speak = function() {
    alert( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
};

var b1 = Object.create( Bar );
b1.init( "b1" );
var b2 = Object.create( Bar );
b2.init( "b2" );

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

Why doesn't Kyle use the second argument of `Object.create` to initialize the objets `b1` and `b2`? While he does make the distinction between a polyfilled `Object.create` and one that's not, the book was published 5 years after the release of ES5. So, what's wrong with using the official `Object.create`?

From You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes

> The second argument to Object.create(..) specifies property names to add to the newly created object, via declaring each new property's property descriptor (see Chapter 3). Because polyfilling property descriptors into pre-ES5 is not possible, this additional functionality on Object.create(..) also cannot be polyfilled.

Here is how I would implement it. It's not quite the same object structure, but the end result is pretty much the same. Anyway, you should get the gist of it.

```
var Foo = {
    init: function() {
        return Object.create(Foo, {identify: {value: function () {
                                return "I am " + this.me;
                             }}});
    }
};

var Bar = Foo.init();

Bar.init = function (who) {
    return Object.create(Bar, {me: {value: who},
                            speak: {value: function () {
                                 alert( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
                                }}});
}

var b1 = Bar.init("b1");
var b2 = Bar.init("b2");

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

Comment: Maybe because code used to demonstrate a concept should be clear in its intentions, rather than concise?

Comment: Then why use anything post-ES3?

Comment: Is all the code you write for demonstrative purposes?

Comment: Look, I'm just asking if there is any difference (beyond demonstrative ones) between initializing objects with Object.create and doing so with a local method. You know, like performance issues. No need to be obtuse about it.

Comment: "*there is nothing novel about it*" - indeed, it's just plain prototypical inheritance, the rawest form of the ages-old prototype concept. I believe he's credited mostly for popularising the idea, and for coining the term OLOO.

Comment: "*Why doesn't Kyle use the second argument of `Object.create` to initialize the objets `b1` and `b2`?*" - how would you do that? `Object.create` cannot call a method like `init`.

Comment: "*While he does make the distinction between a polyfilled `Object.create` and one that's not*" - can you quote what you are referring to here? Nothing in the code excerpt you posted makes such a distinction.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I made some edits to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggested `init` method has become a factory function now, it no longer should be a method. This is no longer OLOO. Notice you also that your `Foo.init` method no longer takes the argument for the `me` value, although it should be its responsibility.

Comment: In plain prototypical inheritance, you wouldn't use methods at all. You'd just write `const Foo = Object.create(Object.prototype); Foo.identify = …; const Bar = Object.create(Foo); Bar.speak = …; ` then `const b = Object.create(Bar); b.me = 'b1'; b.speak(); const f = Object.create(Foo); f.me = 'f1'; console.log(f.identify());`

Comment: "*While he does [care about] a polyfilled `Object.create` [·´…], the book was published 5 years after the release of ES5*" - same reason why today you still hear people talk about transpiling JavaScript to ES5, five years after the release of ES6. It is an issue that's worth mentioning, especially when using a feature that cannot be polyfilled. (Btw, in modern JS you'd combine `Object.create` with `Object.assign` for the purpose of OLOO).